# Spring boot with hal response always defined structure

Tags: java, json, rest, spring-boot, hal

I have a spring boot application that returns a collection of resources using PagedResources and HAL.

This is an example of a common response:

```
{
  "_embedded": {
    "mappings": [
      {
        "formId": "857353204373673",
        "formName": null,
        .....
      }
    ]
  },
  "_links": {.....},
  "page": {.....}
}
```

Otherwise, if the collection to return is null (perhaps empty) the response will be:

```
{
  "_links": {.....},
  "page": {.....}
}
```

I would like to have a response that always returns a JSON which includes the _embedded node with all its fields(Obviously empty) like:

```
{
  "_embedded": {
    "mappings": []
  },
  "_links": {.....},
  "page": {.....}
}
```

My choice is to always let the clients see the whole structure of my JSON (Maybe this is not the best practice?).

Here's the code snippet:

```
@RequestMapping(
        method = RequestMethod.GET,
        path = "/mappings")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
@ApiImplicitParams({
        @ApiImplicitParam(name = "page", dataType = "int", paramType = "query"),
        @ApiImplicitParam(name = "size", dataType = "int", paramType = "query"),
        @ApiImplicitParam(name = "sort", dataType = "string",  paramType = "query", allowMultiple = true),
        @ApiImplicitParam(name = RestConfiguration.HEADER_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE, dataType = "string",  paramType = "header", defaultValue = RestConfiguration.DEFAULT_LOCALE_TAG)
})
public PagedResources<MappingResource> getMappings(@ApiParam(required = true) @PathVariable final Integer customerId,
                                                   @ApiIgnore @PageableDefault final Pageable pageable,
                                                   HttpServletRequest request) {

    ApplicationResourcesValidator.validateCustomerId(customerId);
    if (customerRepository.findOne(customerId) == null) {
        throw new CustomerNotFoundException(customerId);
    }

    customerIdProvider.set(customerId);

    Page<UserdbFormMapping> mappings = userdbFormMappingRepository.findAllIfUserdbValid(pageable);

    MappingResourceAssembler mappingResourceAssembler = new MappingResourceAssembler(
            MappingController.class,
            MappingResource.class,
            customerId,
            facebookApiClient,
            userdbRepository,
            userdbFormMappingRepository,
            userdbFormMappingFieldRepository,
            userdbFormSubscriptionLogCacheRepository,
            persistenceManager);

    LOGGER.info("serving " + request.getRequestURI());

    return mappingPagedResourceAssembler.toResource(mappings, mappingResourceAssembler);
}
```

Any suggestion is appreciated!

Thanks in advance,
Andrea.

Comment: Could you a little bit clarify? Do you mean that you are currently wondering whether or not showing the collection structure when a collection returns null or empty?

Comment: Yeah, I wonderng how to always display the _embedded HAL property even if the collection to return is empty and/or null.

Comment: You are right wishing for that. It is definitely better when it comes to parsing the response in the client. That being said,  it is quite likely that you can do that by not throwing the 'customer not found exception' or by changing the logic where the exception is caught. About the latter, I don't see where that happens in the code above.

Comment: With Spring Boot `1.4.0.RELEASE`, You can register a custom serializer using `@JsonComponent`.